# gobject-introspection 1.68 not installing in Macos Mojave

Tags: python, macos, gdal

I am trying to install `gobject-introspection` v-1.68 as a dependency of gdal  on my macbook pro (macOS mojave version 10.14.6 (18G9028)). I am installing it through brew. But it is showing some errors

```
==> meson --prefix=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.68.0 --libdir=/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.68.0/lib --buildtype=release --wrap-mode=nofallback -Dpython=/usr/local/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/pyt
==> ninja -v
Last 15 lines from /Users/nati/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gobject-introspection/02.ninja:
../tests/gimarshallingtests.c:4654: Warning: GIMarshallingTests: gi_marshalling_tests_object_vfunc_caller_allocated_out_parameter: argument a: Unresolved type: 'GValue*'
<unknown>:: Fatal: GIMarshallingTests: warnings configured as fatal
<unknown>:: Fatal: GIMarshallingTests: warnings configured as fatal
```

```
[143/163] /usr/local/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 tools/g-ir-scanner --quiet --output=tests/Everything-1.0.gir --no-libtool --reparse-validate --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/gir --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/gir --warn-all --warn-error --namespace=Everything --nsversion=1.0 --include=Gio-2.0 --library=everything-1.0 -L /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/tests -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests tests/everything.c tests/everything.h
[144/163] /usr/local/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 tools/g-ir-scanner --quiet --output=tests/scanner/Utility-1.0.gir --no-libtool --reparse-validate --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/gir --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/gir --warn-all --warn-error --namespace=Utility --nsversion=1.0 --include=GObject-2.0 --pkg=gobject-2.0 --library=utility-1.0 --c-include=utility.h -L /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/tests/scanner -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests/scanner -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests/scanner/.. ../tests/scanner/utility.c ../tests/scanner/utility.h
FAILED: tests/scanner/Utility-1.0.gir
/usr/local/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 tools/g-ir-scanner --quiet --output=tests/scanner/Utility-1.0.gir --no-libtool --reparse-validate --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/gir --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/gir --warn-all --warn-error --namespace=Utility --nsversion=1.0 --include=GObject-2.0 --pkg=gobject-2.0 --library=utility-1.0 --c-include=utility.h -L /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/tests/scanner -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests/scanner -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests/scanner/.. ../tests/scanner/utility.c ../tests/scanner/utility.h
../tests/scanner/utility.h:63: Warning: Utility: utility_object_watch_dir: argument func: Missing (scope) annotation for callback without GDestroyNotify (valid: call, async)
../tests/scanner/utility.h:63: Warning: Utility: utility_object_watch_dir: argument destroy: Unresolved type: 'GDestroyNotify'
<unknown>:: Fatal: Utility: warnings configured as fatal
<unknown>:: Fatal: Utility: warnings configured as fatal

[145/163] /usr/local/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3 tools/g-ir-scanner --quiet --output=tests/scanner/GetType-1.0.gir --no-libtool --reparse-validate --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/gir --add-include-path /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/gir --namespace=GetType --nsversion=1.0 --identifier-prefix=GetType --symbol-prefix=gettype --include=GObject-2.0 --pkg=gobject-2.0 --library=gettype-1.0 --c-include=gettype.h -L /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/build/tests/scanner -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests/scanner -I /private/tmp/gobject-introspection-20210508-20798-1v33dpn/gobject-introspection-1.68.0/tests/scanner/.. ../tests/scanner/gettype.c ../tests/scanner/gettype.h
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!
```

What can I do to solve this problem?